# OOPs! Errors with S4 OOP code and a cryptic error

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'm trying to set up an S4 object and I can't figure out what is wrong with it. The object is meant to help ease printing out a bunch of demographic information. Here is the code:

```
dem <- setClass("dem", 
                slots = list(num_cats = "numeric",
                          cat_labels = "character",
                          cat_counts = "integer",
                          cat_percents = "character")
       )
setMethod("print", 
          "dem",
          function(.Object,
                   x = numeric(0)) {
              .Object <- dem
              paste(dem@num_cats)
          })

make_dem = function(dd) {
    dem(
        num_cats = length(dd$values),
        cat_labels = dd$values$value,
        cat_counts = dd$values$frequency,
        cat_percents = calc_dem_percents(cat_counts)
    ) }
```

Here is the referenced function `calc_dem_percents`, and sorry for not putting it in the first go-round:

```
calc_dem_percents <- function(cat_counts) { #calc percents for each category
    tot <- sum(cat_counts) #get total number of categories
    cat_counts <- cat_counts %>% as_tibble() #change to tibble because I do 
                                             # that
    percent(cat_counts$value/tot) # return percents as a list, one per cat
}
```

`cat_counts` comes from `dd$values$frequency`.

Everything goes through without any errors. Then, when I use

```
gender <- make_dem(dd)
```

I get

```
##  Error in initialize(value, ...) : 
## no slot of name "refMethods" for this object of 
## "classRepresentation"
```

What am I doing wrong? I see a lot of conflicting documentation out there and am thoroughly confused.

FYI, this is the structure of `dd`:

```
List of 5    
 $ descript: chr "Gender"    
 $ units   : NULL    
 $ format  : NULL    
 $ counts  : Named num [1:3] 447 32 2    
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "n" "missing" "distinct"    
 $ values  :List of 2    
  ..$ value    : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"    
  ..$ frequency: num [1:2(1d)] 308 139    
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "describe"
```

Thanks!

Comment: what does the function `calc_dem_percents` do? If you set `options(error=recover)` could you add the results to the question? It will help identify where the error is happening.

Comment: @JDL sorry for not including the function. It's there now. Where would I put `options(error = recover)`?

Comment: at the top of the code (what it does is change R's behaviour so that when an error happens, you get a stack trace and can browse through the variables in each scope.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is almost certainly in this line:

```
  cat_percents = calc_dem_percents(cat_counts)
```

There are two things that might be wrong:

- you reference a function `calc_dem_percents`, which doesn't exist (did you write it yourself and forget to include it in the question, or is it from a particular R library?). That function might have a bug in it.
- you reference the variable `cat_counts`, but this variable doesn't exist yet (it would do if the arguments to `dem` were named, but they aren't). Better to use `dd$values$frequency` instead.

Perhaps you defined your own variable `cat_counts` (or declared it as a class) outside of the scope of this question and it is using that, but in that case I can't help you.

If none of the above works, try evaluating each of the expressions that you assign to the slots separately, and see if you get what you expect (in particular, be sure to check the `class` of each of those things).

Comment: See edits regarding `calc_dem_percents`. `cat_counts` is part of the class definition. Should I be treating it differently?

Comment: I don't think you can reference it in that context. You are only allowed to reference other arguments to a function if they are named in the function definition, rather than the class definition. (E.g. `c(a=1,b=2,d=a)` returns an error because `c` doesn't have named arguments.) Does your code work if you replace `cat_counts` with `dd$values$frequency` in that line?

Comment: I think it must have been an improvement, but there was still the same error. See my post below, because following your advice I did find the answer. Thank you, @JDL!

Answer (score 0):

@JDL, I carried out your suggestion to use `d$values$frequency` instead of `cat_counts` and still had the same error. Then I went back and walked through `make_dem_class`, also as you suggested, watching values update one by one. And there was the problem: the initial declaration of `cat_counts` as part of the dem class. I called it an integer, but it was two integers, one "count" for each "cat" or category, the number of which was `cat_num`--in this case, 2. When I checked the class of the object from which I was taking `cat_counts` I found:

```
class(dd$values$frequency)
# "array"
```

So `cat_counts` ought to have been declared as an array, not as an integer. Here is the correct code:

```
dem <- setClass("dem", 
                slots = list(num_cats = "numeric",
                             cat_labels = "character",
                             cat_counts = "array",
                             cat_percents = "character")
       )

    setMethod("print", 
              "dem",
              function(.Object,
                       x = numeric(0)) {
                  .Object <- dem
                  print(dem@cat_labels)
                  print(dem@cat_counts)
                  print(dem@cat_percents)
              })

    make_dem = function(dd) {
        dem(
            num_cats = length(dd$values),
            cat_labels = dd$values$value,
            cat_counts = dd$values$frequency,
            cat_percents = calc_dem_percents(dd$values$frequency)
        )
    }
```

And it works. My very grateful thanks.

But the next step does not. Using `make_dem_class()` I have created `dem_obj`, a demographic object of class `dem`. I did it like this:

```
> dem_object <- make_dem_class(dd)
> dem_object

An object of class "dem"
Slot "num_cats":
[1] 2

Slot "cat_labels":
[1] "Male"   "Female"

Slot "cat_counts":
[1] 308 139

Slot "cat_percents":
[1] "68.9%" "31.1%"
```

Here is its structure:

```
> str(dem_object)
Formal class 'dem' [package ".GlobalEnv"] with 4 slots
  ..@ num_cats    : int 2
  ..@ cat_labels  : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..@ cat_counts  : num [1:2(1d)] 308 139
  ..@ cat_percents: chr [1:2] "68.9%" "31.1%"
```

But there seems to be something wrong with my `setMethod` for print, because when I try to print it, this happens:

```
Error in print(dem@cat_labels) : 
  no slot of name "cat_labels" for this object of class "classGeneratorFunction"
```

So much to learn about working with S4 objects. . . .

Comment: I don't doubt this solved your problem, but I don't think it is for the reason you think. It is fine to use "integer" as the slot definition even if it is actually a *vector* of integers. Bear in mind, in R, `447` is *not* an integer (try `is.integer(447)` if you don't believe me!) — the correct way of specifying an integer is to append an "L" as in `447L`. `is.integer(447L)` is TRUE. Changing to "array" allowed the data to be of type "numeric" as well as "integer" which may be why it worked.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Thanks for the lesson. :)